# Scaling a background image relative to its own size?

Tags: css, background-image, scale

I have a div in which I have set the background to a certain image. Let's say for example that the div is 300x300, and that the original background image size is 200x200.

I want to scale the background image by a certain percentage relative to itself. For example, if I were to scale by 200%, I want the background image to now be 400x400 pixels and be slightly cut off. But the only css property I've been able to find is the `background-size` property, which scales with a percentage relative to the parent div (eg. with 200% scale, the background image would become 600x600).

Is there any way to achieve scaling relative to the background image itself?

Comment: Have you tried background-size:cover;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I actually found a way to do this using purely css. The issue I was having of course, is that `background-size` scales relative to the div we're setting the background of, as opposed to the image size itself.

The workaround is that we can wrap the div in a parent div with the width and height that we want, then set the inner div's width and height equal to that of the background image we're using. This way we can scale the inner div according to the background's size, since they are equal in size, then crop off the correct amount by setting the parent to overflow: hidden.

*The only catch is that we must use server-side rendering to set the inner div's width and height to the image's width and height without using javascript.

For example:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width:{{bgimgwidth}}; height:{{bgimgheight}}; background: url('{{url}}'); background-size: 200%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **JavaScript**

See this [JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/HfG9j/1/embedded/result/) ... ([Source](http://jsfiddle.net/HfG9j/1/))

### HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#box{
    background: #fff center no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/84256/batman-logo-black.jpg);
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('box'),
    style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);

    var imageSrc = bi.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2').split(',')[0];     

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    var width = image.width,
        height = image.height;

    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundSize = (width * 2.00) + 'px ' + (height * 2.00) + 'px'; 
}
```

Hope this will help you ..

Answer (score -3):

In this case you could set `background-size: 67%;`. So the background image is 67% of the parent div.

- div 300x300, backgorund 201x201
- div 600x600, backgorund 402x402

Greetings

Comment: The background image will be of variable size. This is why I specifically said that I need to scale relative to the image's size itself, not the parent div.

Comment: I see, sorry. Do you want to do this by using css only? I could tell you how to do that with javascript.

Comment: I would certainly prefer to do this using only css, but it is seeming like that is not possible. So sure, feel free to post the js workaround to this.